# Autotype deprecated ant built

Tags: java, ant, weblogic12c

I am currently migrating to weblogic12c and it seems that ant task autotype has been deprecated.

Has anyone ran into this issue before? Have not found any documentation on how to proceed with manual build now.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a different task that should be used instead of autotype, but, a work-around is to specifically load the older weblogic.jar file during the build. That's what I've been doing until we find a better solution. Example:

ant -d D:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar generate-typeinfot

Comment: sorry that was -lib not -d